# How can I create a target for an _existing_ library?

Tags: cmake

In CMake, we can `add_library(mylib file1.cpp file2.cpp)` and have a `mylib.a` in the library path get built. We can also `target_include_directories(mylib INTERFACE some/directory)`, which effects targets depending on `mylib`.

But what if I have a library to begin with, which I will *not* be compiling. How can I add a target relating to it? That what I add as a dependency, will cause the `.a` file to be linked against, and for which I can set `target_include_directories()` ?

Note: I'm asking about CMake 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

CMake provide an alternate signature for libraries that are already compiled:

```
add_library(
    mynamespace::mylib 
    STATIC                # or it could be SHARED
    IMPORTED
)
```

See the [official CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) for more details.

with that you'll be able to add properties to the target doing so

```
set_target_properties(
    mynamespace::mylib
    PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "path/to/libmylib.a"
)
```

Little precision here, if you're using a Windows DLL, you must pass the DLL file's path in `IMPORTED_LOCATION` and set another property `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` that points to the `.lib` file, (not very handy).

Note that there is also a equivalent properties per configuration (Debug, and Release), that will need another property to be set (`IMPORTED_CONFIGURATION`), e.g. `IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG`.

See also [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html#prop_tgt:IMPORTED_LOCATION) and [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_IMPLIB.html?highlight=imported_implib) in the documentation.

To avoid missing include files you can also precise the include directory using `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY` property

```
set_target_properties(
    mynamespace::mylib 
    PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "path/to/mylib/include"
)
```

With this, upon link declaration using `target_link_libraries()`, CMake will read information of the imported target and will add include directories implicitly.

Official documentation [reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html?highlight=interface_include_directories).